# Running SQL script script/s on multiple databases at the same time (Parallel execution)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, deployment, sqlcmd

I currently use sqlcmd to execute scripts on a database within my deployment process. Now with multiple database one solution is to use this very script in a batch or foreach database. The problem with this, it applies the script to the database one at a time. I need something that can save time.

Can SQLCMD execute a script on multiple database in Parallel? If not, are there a script command I can leverage to accomplish this?

There are similar questions, but none with the right solution or the stress that it has to be a method to execute in Parallel which is the main goal.
The tool SQL Multi Script does exactly this, but its not open source plus I prefer scripting it out.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using the following.

1. The user will set which databases to deploy to in a specific instance.
2. `Foreach` database it will generate a set of SQLCMD commands `foreach` script to deploy and place this in a batch file.

For Example: S`QLCMD_Commands_DB1.bat` and `SQLCMD_Commands_DB2.bat`

1. `Foreach` batch file created with will then generate a new master batch file with the START commands.

   START "" "SQLCMD_Commands_DB1.bat"
   START "" "SQLCMD_Commands_DB2.bat"
2. Execute the Master batch file which will deploy the database scripts in Parallel. I written this and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SSMS to run your SQLCMD script, you can use a group query to run again more than one server.  I am not completely sure if it runs in parallel or not.  [Look here for more information](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964743%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. However I am using sqlcmd from the command line not through SSMS.